# python requests library not getting the HTML from playstore website?

Tags: python, html, web, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to access the HTML content from the playstore using the requests library of python. But due to its AJAX calls I am not able to get the correct content. Anyone please help me out on this.

Comment: Where is the code that you have tried? Read here on [how to as a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an extremely common question. You can't work with pages that use AJAX using just requests - you need to use Selenium. Good Luck!

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html